# Android Action Bar Menu Item

Tags: android, android-intent

I am adding an item to the action bar and when the activity first loads it's correct where that item only exist in the action bar. Then when I got to another activity and come back via an `Intent` that menu item gets duplicated. It still shows up in the action bar but it also shows up in the menu.

Here is my code going from one activity to another. This is coming from the add screen to the home screen. When it gets to the home screen the Add action bar item shows up both in the menu and the action bar. When the Home initially loads it only shows up in the action bar like it should.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Add.this, Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is my menu inflator on Home activity

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.gas_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This activity is extending tabactivity which may be the cause of it not reload. I did a small test against a class extending activity and it seems to be working fine. I should probably just replace tab activity then as it's been deprecated.

Comment: Have you tried to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in `onResume()` when you are returning to the first activity?

Comment: you can explicitly unload the actionBar before the intent. or kill it at start of activity A and rebuild it --> invalidateOptionsMenu() does it

Comment: I think there are some issues with the existing state. onCreateOptionsMenu() seems to be executed every time you return from an Activity. calling menu.clear() before inflating the menu should work for you.

Comment: These suggestions don't seem to be working is there anything else I can try? Also is there a good way to debug what is happening with the menu. It appears like even clearing it may clear the menu options but the action bar option stays. Is that possible?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "it may clear the menu options but the action bar option stays". The menu which you inflate is basically the ActionBar. I do not exactly know how the ActionBar takes the inflated menu but it seems that although you reset the menu the ActionBar is not refreshed. You may have to reset the ActionBar too. Since having a menu in the ActionBar is a common task I do not understand why you have such big problems. Are you using any libraries which may effect this? E.g. AndroidAnnotations?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you invoke super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) instead of returning always true. I tried this code and it worked for me.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    final MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_file, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```